# Python incrementing a xml parse

Tags: python, xml-parsing, increment

Hello I am a programming in python to make a xml parse. And While I can get it to parse out the first xml tag. I want to be able to do it all in the file. but I dont know how to do it. Here is the code I am sure I am missing something I know I gotta replace the 0 with something that can be counted but can't seem to figure out what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I can't really write it here without it looking funny. Hope that helps.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def xml_data ():
    f = open('C:/opidea.xml','r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    dom = minidom.parseString(data)
    list(data) = ic

    xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('author')[0].toxml()

    xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<author>','Changes by: ').replace('</author>','')

    xmlDate = dom.getElementsByTagName('date')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

    xmlPath = dom.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].toxml()   

    xmlPathm =xmlPath.replace('<kind>',' What Changed: ').replace('</path>','') 

    xmlMsg = dom.getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].toxml()

    xmlMsgm =xmlMsg.replace('<msg>','Comments: ').replace('</msg>','')

    content = ''
    content += xmlData + '\n'
    content += xmlDate + '\n'
    content += xmlPathm + '\n'
    content += xmlMsgm + '\n'

    send_email(content)

def send_email(content):
    print content
```

And here is what the xml data would look like.

```
<log>
<logentry
 revision="33185">
 <author>glv</author>
<date>2012-08-06T21:01:52.494219Z</date>
<paths>
<path
  action="M"
  kind="dir">/branches/somefolder</path>
</paths>
  <msg>PATCH_BRANCH:N/A
    BUG_NUMBER:N/A
   FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
OVERVIEW:N/A
    Adding the SVN log size requirement to the branch 
</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code? It's not hard to format it.

Comment: There you go, I get complains about how it comes out but if you wanna see it, there ya go. Thank you.

Comment: You really need to reformat this. Style matters in Python and expecting us to help with broken code is a bit much. And the screenshot doesn't help. Why not just copy and paste?

Comment: Also, can you post the XML data as well?

Comment: I did just copy and paste this is what i get. I know the formating is not going to be perfect it is never right, frankly i wonder how ppl can copy it over perfectly and I can't. I thought the screen shot would save the trouble. And sure I would add what the xml data is.